# Serial Gabor filter output trouble

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This is code for serial Gabor filters. The problem I am getting is the statement `J = J + abc` should return a final filtered image as a superposition of all filters but only the result of the last iteration is displayed:

```
function [J] = gabor(I)

J = zeros(size(I));

for phi = 5*pi/8:pi/8:pi;
    for theta = 1:0.5:2;
        for filterSize = 4:6;
            sigma = 0.65*theta;
            G = zeros(filterSize);

            for i=(0:filterSize-1)/filterSize
                for j=(0:filterSize-1)/filterSize
                    xprime= j*cos(phi);
                    yprime= i*sin(phi);
                    K = exp(2*pi*theta*sqrt(-1)*(xprime+ yprime));
                    G(round((i+1)*filterSize),round((j+1)*filterSize)) = exp(-(i^2+j^2)/(sigma^2))*K;
                end
            end

        abc = conv2(double(I),double(G),'same');
        J = J + abc;
        end
    end
end
figure; imshow(J);
end
```

---

Here is what the output image looks like:

[image: blah]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut feeling (or it rather looks like...) is that your image output type is `double`, and `imshow` only displays intensities between `[0,1]` for class `double`.  Any values that are below 0 or above 1 get saturated to black or white respectively, which is why your image output only appears to be black or white.  This is also apparent as `J` is defaulted to a `double` type.  Try doing this for your `imshow` command so that it stretches the intensities to fit within the `[0,1]` range:

```
imshow(J, []);
```

Take note that this **does not** modify the image.  It only changes how the image is visualized.  This `imshow` command appears at the end of your code, and so change that command here.

By the way, `sqrt(-1)` is considered bad form.  Use `1j` or `1i` instead, and change your `for` loop indices so that you're not using `i` and `j` as these should be used to represent the complex number.  It has been shown by [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai) that using `i` and `j` as loop indices can lead to poor performance.  You should reserve these for the complex number instead.  Check this post out for more details: [Using i and j as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Also, you probably want to contrast stretch the image so that it does fit between `0` and `1`.  As such, do this before you exit your function:

```
J = im2double(J);
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply but THANKS A TON it worked like the way i wanted to its just that sometimes the error is staring at you and you cant figure it out....thanks again

Comment: @akshay - You're welcome.  If my post helped you, please consider accepting it.  Click on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down vote buttons.  Thanks!